# Strange python error while compiling c++ bitcode with emscripten

Tags: javascript, python, c++, compilation, emscripten

I get this error and I am unsure of why.

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/gitrepos/Othello-tictactoe $ emcc -O2 main.bc OthelloBoard.bc OthelloMove.bc OthelloView.bc TicTacToeBoard.bc TicTacToeMove.bc TicTacToeView.bc -o project.js
    Exception in thread Thread-3:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 380, in _handle_results
    task = get()
    TypeError: ('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', <class
    'subprocess.CalledProcessError'>, ())
```

I followed the tutorial on Emscripten's own site exactly and used the same   -O2 for each bc file. Anybody have any ideas? This project is on github in case u guys need the code for the sources https://github.com/joe564338/othellotictactoelinux/tree/master/Game

Comment: Very strange since I tried compiling it on my desktop computer and it worked. But the program is buggy as hell as inputs are not accepted as they should be...

Comment: Lol got it working somehow but only on mozilla firefox browser. Chrome and IE dont work for whatever reason